# what is wrong in this sql syntax?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT * 
FROM ua_campus_report_campus (old) 
WHERE article LIKE 'Ed %'
```

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(old) WHERE article LIKE Ed % LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1

[table names image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGPTl.png)

Comment: Remove `(old)` from this query. Voting to close this as a typo.

Comment: but i have table with the same name

Comment: then put the tablename in backticks `´ua_campus_report_campus (old)`´

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Identifiers that contain spaces or special characters must be escaped. Normal MySQL pattern is to enclose identifier in backtick characters:

```
  SELECT t.* 
    FROM `ua_campus_report_campus (old)` t
   WHERE t.article LIKE 'Ed %'
```

Also note that best practice is qualify all column references with the table name or alias.

(It's also possible to escape identifiers by enclosing them in double quotes when `sql_mode` includes `ANSI_QUOTES`.)